# Pass Class As Parameter in Javascript to Java

Tags: javascript, java, parameter-passing

So I recently joined in on a project where they use Java as a backend to a game and JavaScript as a frontend that communicates with the server. I know that JavaScript is dynamic and that's fine and all, but if I'm requesting information from the server where they have methods such as ...

```
public <T extends Component> T getProperty(Class<? extends Component> property, int id) {
    return (T) mapper.get(property).get(id);
}
```

You can see the issue here, right? How would I exactly do a request in JavaScript, passing in .class as a parameter? I've tried researching online, but it doesn't seem this is a frequented question?

Comment: what do you mean by , passing in .class as a parameter

Comment: Needs more context. You can probably build a map of acceptable classnames and have your JS pass in those names. The server endpoint would translate from name to Class. Raw, unvetted classnames sound like a security problem.

Answer (score 0):

The language of frontend does not matter.

Think about it - how frontend is communicating with server? I suppose it goes through HTTP, right? So no matter which language you have, it has to create standard HTTP request, which has some headers, fields etc.

I dont know your project, but usually call from frontend is transformed through some component to standard Java instance, so you can use it effectively (i.e. receiving form data or JSON and creating instance of class that has these fields)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the class name, instead:

```
public <T extends Component> T getProperty(String propertyClassName, int id) {
    return (T) mapper.get(Class.forName(propertyClassName)).get(id);
}
```

Please note that this is a sign of tight coupling between the client and the server. There are alternative protocol-level mechanisms to pass this information, such as just enum-based "types", which make it easy to document and to minimize the mutual impact of changes between the server and the client.

Comment: Oh! Enum based type sounds good too. You're talking about having an enum with the .class as the value, right?

Comment: @JonNguyen This depends broadly on the frameworks you use to expose your services. But it's generally a bad idea to expose your server's implementation knowledge to the client, that's why there are architectures such as REST and many other web frameworks. *About my 'enum' comment*: I meant if you have a clear API definition for your services, you would ideally have a model for the entity you're returning. In that case, an enum value would be appropriate to replace such intimate information as class names. It's just one approach or alternative implementation (a safer one, though)

Comment: Tight coupling aside, the server should at least have a whitelist of acceptable classnames. Otherwise a malicious client could trigger random class loading. But I agree, implementation-independent mapping of "stable" names is better.